# I have an issue with Stepping on gas and no increase in speed

Tags: engine, transmission, fuel-system, fuel-injection

It only happens rarely.. but sometimes when stepping down the gas
it would suddenly max out the speed gauge, and you hear the very loud engine
noise as if i stepped down the gas all the way, but what is weird is the
fact that car doesn't accelerate much if any at all!

it happened twice during the past month, no pattern in when this happens other
than stepping on the gas like you normally would..

Open to suggestion on what is wrong.

Comment: Is this an automatic or manual transmission? What make/model/year/mileage?

Comment: @Paulster2 This is automatic , infinity i30t, It is an old car 2001 model and 140 on mileage

Comment: I had problems with my 2002 Jeep, accelerator seemed to not want to get speed, well I checked to see what was wrong at the Auto Zone was told from meter indication code reading it had to do with the Trans mission, (auto), I checked the codes and read governor and something else , I bought the 2 parts (small but costly) took it to shop also need to buy fluid, and gasket, replace them while changed fluid and that was it , thank you auto zone..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With your added information, this sounds like there is a definite problem with the transmission. Your description leads me to believe it probably has something to do with the clutches being worn out in conjunction with low line pressures (or some such). I would definitely believe the transmission is due for an overhaul. If you pull the dipstick, does the transmission fluid smell burnt and/or appear dark brown in color? If so, this is another tell tale sign. The soft parts in an automatic transmission will only last so long before they start exhibiting these types of problems. I would highly doubt there is anything wrong with the engine (at this point).

Comment: What would be the suggested fix, again this is not a fancy new car so any costly fixes wouldn't really make sense. i was thinking of just using the car until it breaks?

Comment: You could possibly get the transmission flushed and have new fluid put in, but that's a crap shoot. Sometimes, if it hasn't been done in a while, it can actually make the situation worse. You can also check to ensure your tranny fluid is topped off. If it's low, you might experience these types of issues. Thirdly, there are transmission conditioners, which can "fluff up" the old soft parts and get them to last a little while longer. I don't know how well they work, but do know they are out there. Do not over fill your transmission, however, as this will cause leakage issues.

Comment: Maybe but I may be wrong there could be a problem with clutch hydraulic/mechatronic, I mean it could make laq between changing gears so it´s stucked in between gears and that´s where rpm´s got high and then to normal again, but I have no experience with that, I would try some A/T diagnostic first, then you see if it´s trans. control unit or some part which cause this problem.

Comment: @Mustafa105 ... anyway you look at it, doing any type of diagnostics on it is going to start costing money, which I believe from reading what Victor has said he doesn't want to pursue.

Answer (score 3):

Your clutch slips probably, soon or later you won´t be able to accelerate anymore, just to be sure I understood it like that, you step on gas pedal, rpm´s get high, no acceleration, then when you step out a bit it catches and car starts to accelerate again, right?

Comment: This is a good explanation ... **if** it's a manual transmission. Waiting on the OP to respond to give an accurate answer.

Comment: Its automatic transmittion Thank you for the respond. and it DOES not get better it just keeps happening once it starts. but i think if the car is shutdown and go from a new restart it works fine again.. when this happens the car rpm meter can't be hold more than 2-3 (out of 8-10?) idk the exact number but when it does happen everytime u press gas and goes over that it just skyrocket the meter and max out the engine noise

Comment: I went to a few mech some of them told me to rebuild the whole transmition some say its the eninge so im really confused at what is really going on! i don't want to spend thousand on fixxing such a core issue that might not even be the source of this..